# replace if statments with clean code and best practices

Tags: python, solid-principles

It is a simple code, what I am looking for is to learn the best practices that I can implement, when trying to refactor the show method, to a method that is closed to modifications. so that in the future if they ask me to enter a new card with a value of type chain, it is not necessary to modify this method.

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, suit, value):
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = value

def show(self):
    if self.value == 1:
        value = "Ace"
    elif self.value == 11:
        value = "Jack"
    elif self.value == 12:
        value = "Queen"
    elif self.value == 13:
        value = "King"
    else:
        value = self.value

    return f'{value} of {self.suit}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emulate a switch-case statement with a dictionary:

```
def show(self):
    value = {
        1: 'Ace', 11: 'Jack',
        12: 'Queen', 13: 'King'
    }.get(self.value, self.value)

    return f'{value} of {self.suit}'
```

What’s happening here is that we are creating a mapping of card numerical value to card name. Immediately after creation of this object, we use the `dict.get` method to try and retrieve the corresponding name based on `self.value`. The second argument is a fallback to ensure if the lookup fails, we use the current value.

Comment: but I would have to enter to modify the show method.

Comment: The `show` method is the only method that needs refactoring. If you cannot modify it, there isn’t much to improve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to obtain a show method, with open / close principle.

Comment: There isn’t any inheritance/subclassing in your code so I don’t think that applying the open/closed principle is useful. Unless you are going to subclass class `Card`, you can’t make it any more abstract.

Answer (score 0):

For me the code looks ok, but if you like, you could use a dictionary:

```
value = {1: "Ace", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}.get(self.value,self.value)
```

Comment: but I would have to enter to modify the show method.

Comment: then the only way I see is to move the dictionary to the `__init__` method, but I don't see any real advantage in it (i.e. self.values = { ... } in `__init__` and then `value = self.values.get(self.value,self.value)` in `show`